# how to deploy metro app to windows rt device WITHOUT STORE

Tags: windows-store, sideloading, windows-rt

I developped a metro app and its for my company only. so I'm not going to upload it to windows store.

I want to use my app on Windows RT devices (over 400).
I tried to open appx with powershell but powershell needs developer license

How can I deploy my app to rt devices ?

Answer (score 3):

Therefore you need Windows 8 Enterprise, which enables you, to "sideload" an App directly on your devices

http://blogs.technet.com/b/scd-odtsp/archive/2012/09/27/windows-8-sideloading-requirements.aspx

---

- You must enable the Allow all trusted applications to install Group Policy setting
- You must activate the sideloading product key on a device running Windows 8 Enterprise or Windows® 8 Pro. You must activate the sideloading product key on a device running Windows RT

Comment: thing is my company already bought windows RT devices
is there anything to do for windows RT devices

Comment: Yes, you need to activate sideloading on your RT-Devices:<br>
- You need to buy a $30 side-loading product activation key that is per device, and which is non-transferable. So to side-load apps on your Surface RT (for example) you need to buy a $30 key. These keys come in packs of 100, so the minimum price is $3000.

http://www.lhotka.net/weblog/CostToEnableSideloadingOnAWindows8Device.aspx

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/windowsstore/archive/2012/04/25/deploying-metro-style-apps-to-businesses.aspx