# Windows 8 Store applications as enterprise software

Tags: c#, windows-runtime, windows-store-apps, touchscreen

I'm writing a Windows 8 Store application but the application is for internal uses within my company. The application needs to run on 100+ tablets so the installation process needs to be easy.

So, I've been using the Windows 8 Store template to create my application but I now need to get this application on my devices. How can I do this without going through the Windows 8 store release process?

I've sideloaded the application on a few tablets for testing but I needed a developers licence for this and it expires every 30 days.

So is there anyway to release windows 8 store application as an enterprise solution?

I could use WPF to create my apps but the controls just aren't as smooth or nice for the touch screen environment.

Any help would be great. Thanks

Comment: Is it meant for [windows-rt](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bwindows-rt%5D+deploy) ? I am unsure who much is true but i have heard from a colleague that there is no easy way to distribute  WindowsRT apps internally. Although [this answer seems to tell a different story](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14935692/how-to-deploy-metro-app-to-windows-rt-device-without-store/14935721#14935721)

Comment: The tablets would be full windows 8 and I'd prefer to run the application via the desktop for greater control

Comment: What technology did you use -  [windows-runtime](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/windows-runtime/synonyms) or [win-js](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/winjs)?

Comment: Take a look at this article: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/windowsstore/archive/2012/04/25/deploying-metro-style-apps-to-businesses.aspx.

Comment: Thanks for that article. Some good notes on there.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [link provided by takemyoxygen](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/windowsstore/archive/2012/04/25/deploying-metro-style-apps-to-businesses.aspx) already gives a lot of technical details. I'd just like to add a couple of additional notes.

Not all versions of Windows 8 have the sideloading license for installing Windows Store apps outside the store:

- With Windows 8 Enterprise machines joined to a domain you're ready to go.
- With Windows 8 Pro (domain joined or not) and Windows 8 Enterprise outside a domain you need to buy a special activation key (sold in batches of 100).
- With Windows 8 there's no way to get a sideloading license.
- With Windows RT (ARM) you need the activation key. The machine can't be joined to a domain.

Once you have a sideloading license, you can install a Windows Store app package:

- You can manually run the installation script creted by Visual Studio along with the package.
- You can set up a group policy if you have Microsoft System Center and the machines are domain joined.
- For Windows RT machines you can use Windows Intune (as a standalone service or Microsoft System Center add on) to create an internal store for installing Windows Store apps.

Make sure you visit [Lhotka's blog](http://www.lhotka.net/weblog/Windows8WinRTSideloadingUpdate.aspx) to read more on the sideloading subject.