# Windows Store app - Sideloading & beta testing

Tags: c#, windows-store-apps

I've recently started developing a Windows Store app. I provide the app as a package to several beta test user. They install the app and they have to log on with their windows live account to get a developer license. My problem is now the expiration date of one month of the installed apps. Is it possible to extend the expiration date by buying a license or is there a better way for beta tests?
I already developed Windows Phone apps. In the Windows Phone Dev Center is it possible to release beta packages. This would be a great solution for my issue, but it seems to be only a Windows Phone Dev Center feature and not possible for Windows Store apps (Windows 8).
Thanks!

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17542995/windows-8-store-applications-as-enterprise-software and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12922935/is-side-loading-apps-onto-a-windows-rt-device-allowed

Comment: @Xyroid it's not a duplicate. beta testing purposes is totally different from actual side loading for enterprise usage.

Answer (score 0):

there is no official beta package option in the Windows store as there is for Windows Phone.

source: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/dn832612.aspx

if you want to keep the existing way of sending the files to someone and renewing the developer license they can use the following command in powershell window (as admin)

```
Show-WindowsDeveloperLicenseRegistration
```

this will show a popup to renew the license and they can keep using the beta app.