# Deploy Windows Apps to Family and Friends without store, enterprise or development-tools

Tags: windows-10, win-universal-app, uwp

I wrote a App for my family/friends and now we would like deploy it on or PCs. Publishing it in the store is not an option and not everyone has an [Widows Live account](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7493090/how-to-distribute-compiled-windows-8-metro-applications-without-windows-store?rq=1). [Sideloading](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14935692/how-to-deploy-metro-app-to-windows-rt-device-without-store) isn't an option, because we do not own a Enterprise edition.

I found only the three already described ways. Either by publishing it in the store, using the development tools or having the enterprise edition.

Is there a fourth way to deploy a Windows UWP App without using the Windows Store or the need to install a developer certificate? If not, is there a possibility that something similar will be possible in the future?

The [Windows 10 Deployment Tool](https://blogs.windows.com/buildingapps/2015/07/09/just-released-windows-10-application-deployment-tool/) looks like the thing I'm looking for, but i seems to be for mobile phones, or am i wrong?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The future is now! The process is easier on Windows 10 and the linked questions aren't relevant to that version. On Windows 10 users can enable developer mode or side loading in system settings on the "Update & security" page, in the for developers section.

See https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/dn706236.aspx

Comment: Can i use the "Windows 10 Deployment Tool" to deploy my app remotely on other Desktops?

Comment: Once you've enabled developer mode or side-loading you can copy the appx to a desktop system and install it with powershell (add-appxpackage) or an MDM solution (great for enterprises - overkill for your small family scenario) The deployment tool is needed to push the app to a mobile device which doesn't have powershell. The mobile device still needs to have side-loading enabled.

Comment: @RobCaplan-MSFT what if I want to update the App? How can I do it without publishing it on the store.

Answer (score 5):

now with Windows 10 Anniversary update, you could just double click *.appxbundle file to install

Steps:

1. create your package, select no, when prompt "Do you want to build packages to upload to Windows Store?"
2. go to the package folder, double click *.cer, and install the certificate to **Trusted Root Certification Authorities**
3. double click *.appxbundle to install

Client OS Requirement: Win10 14393

UWP Target SDK: 14393

UWP Min SDK: 14393

Comment: Yes, Win10 AU have click-to-run 'App Installer'. But it requires digital signing by trusted root certificate. It's too expensive for personal use. 
https://www.microsoft.com/store/apps/app/9nblggh4nns1

Comment: @pnp0a03 creating a certificate is not necessary to deploy your uwp. basically, you have two options.  1. did not create any certificate, just create the package in vs, and copy that to customer, they can just double click it, a dialogue window will pop up, click on "more info", then click on "run", your uwp will be installed. 2. you can create an app in store, associate your uwp project with the app you registered, and you will have a signed certificate while creating a package

Comment: Hmm… It's differ from my understanding. Here is a my test result with Win10 AU 14393.51.  I've create 3 uwp appxbundle - 1) Non-associated with store, 2) Associated but build for sideload and 3) Associated and build for store publishing. All pkgs were not signed.  Then doubleclick the .appxbundle to launch with appInstaller. But the results were all the same - error "Either you need a new certificate installed for this app package, or ... (0x800B0109)".  I couldn't find the "more info" or "run" option. If possible, could you describe the more detail about it? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

1. On the target device, open the test folder. For example, C:\Projects\MyApp\MyApp\AppPackages\MyApp_1.0.2.0_Test
2. Right-click on the **Add-AppDevPackage.ps1** file, then choose **Run with PowerShell** and follow the prompts.
3. Click the Start button and then type the name of your app to launch it.