# Installing Side-Loaded UWP in Advanced Installer

Tags: powershell, uwp, advanced-installer

I created a UWP and have side-loaded to created the following folder.

[image]

The usual way to install the app would be to run "Add-AppDevPackage" in Powershell, and the script then runs the appxbundle file. I wanted to attach the ps1 file to Advanced Installer to have it install under an msi to make it easier for my company to install the app. However, every time I run the msi, I get a message saying that it has prematurely ended due to an error that's coming from the ps1 file. Is it possible to install a UWP this way, or is there a better way of accomplishing what I want? Here is what my custom action looks like.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to figure out an alternative way to install my UWP without running Powershell. Please follow this link if you are dealing with the same issue.

[UWP installer without powershell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33399614/uwp-installer-without-powershell?rq=1)

Answer (score 2):

The attached .ps1 script will be copied in %temp% location before being launched during installation. Try to add the .appxbundle file as a temporary file in "Files and Folders" page and run again the MSI file.

As another solution you can try, you can add all of your custom actions files as regular files in [Application Folder] directory from "Files and Folders" page and configure your custom action to run as deferred and to launch Script From Disk from the following file path: [APPDIR]Add-AppDevPackage.ps1

Comment: Thank you for responding. However, your solutions did not work.