# How do I share or deploy my Uno Platform app in a simple way?

Tags: uwp, uno-platform

I'm not used to Uno-type development, only fairly simple web dev. I haven't found any info on the Uno site about deploying apps.

My question the same as [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33017016/deploy-windows-apps-to-family-and-friends-without-store-enterprise-or-developme), but that's 5+ yrs old and not Uno, just UWP.

Is there a way to share my Uno UWP app with other Windows users just by sharing files or something like that?

I made a couple of simple C# desktop apps years ago and I just had to share the .exe file. I tried clicking the .exe file in the `.UWP\bin\x86\Debug` folder but that did nothing.

Topics and links also appreciated. Not entirely sure what to look up.

P.S My current app is just from the 'Getting Started' tutorial, nothing serious yet, but I do have that going.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think I found it, working on it...

- **right-click a project > publish > create app packages > sideloading**

Seems right so far.

Answer (score 3):

The UWP head of Uno Platform actually does not use Uno itself - it is a pure UWP app, so the exact same rules apply to it as for UWP development in general. This means you need to package the app to allow sideloading or publish it to the Store.

As for the other targets, each can be deployed using the deployment means native for that target so:

- **Android** - package and publish to a store or sideload the .apk
- **iOS** - package and publish to App Store or sideload the .ipa
- **macOS** - package and publish to macOS App Store
- **WebAssembly** - publish on a hosting service

Comment: Thanks Martin. I'm just not that familiar with desktop work so didn't know at all what to do, for sure. I think I have it going now. Question though: I keep seeing the term "head" but I can't find a good explanation for it. What's the "head", as in, 'the UWP head'?

Comment: Ah, yes, sorry, used a bit of jargon there  . "Platform head" == the platform-specific project in the solution, e.g. MyApp.Android == Android head, etc.

Comment: [Found it](https://platform.uno/docs/articles/uno-app-solution-structure.html).